# Moving Featured Images

Tags: post-thumbnails, import, export, wp-cli

I have been moving around 40k posts from one site to another (different domains), using `wp cli`, all went well, but it seems the featured image weren't imported.

I have now uploaded all media files using `wp cli` and they seem to have the same ID's in the database, as the previous website.

In the `postmeta` table, `_thumbnail_id` already have the correct value, but the featured images show up blank. What should I do?

Comment: Add e.g. a featured image (manually via the UI) to a single post, that should already have one and compare all the related database fields (before/after comparison). Also check the error logs on server and console errors.

Comment: that sounds exhausting, why not use updraft??

Comment: @birgire: I will try that and report.

Comment: @Cam: Already been done, cannot go back. Took days to import everything. Exhausting and frustrating indeed.